# Run task in vscode's integrated terminal from batch (via cli?)

Tags: shell, batch-file, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

As a web developer I normally open up 2 vscode windows, one for Next.js and one for Strapi (my CMS). They rely on each other, so that's why.
Then, in each of these vscode instances, I open up the integrated terminal and do "npm run dev", to spin up dev servers.

I want to automate this somehow. I'm not sure if a batch script is the way to go, but that's where I've started.

I can get vscode to open both projects, but not starting dev servers in the integrated terminals.

I managed to google my way to this (if you have suggestions of improvement, please let me know)

```
@echo off
for %%p in (C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\Programming\nextjs-project C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\Programming\strapi-project) do code -n %%p | exit /b
```

So back to the question, is there some way I can tell vscode to open up the integrated terminal and do "npm run dev" so I don't have to do it manually everytime?

Tried to dig into the vscode CLI docs but couldn't find anything of interest.
Found [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_automating-terminals-with-tasks)  and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) though, could it be useful somehow?

Comment: I have no idea what `code` and `npm` are. Does your batch work to do what you require, other than the `npm` thing? Does it work without the `| exit /b`? You should be able to simply add the `npm` line as the next line in the batch. You could also possibly change to `start "" code...`  `start "" npm...` which establishes 3 separate tasks - the `""` should not be omitted - it becomes the window-title and may be an empty string. Then it's simply a matter of creating a "shortcut" to the batch for clicking and possiblt including the batch in your `startup` directory to run the batch at start-up.

Comment: @Magoo "code" is [Visual Studio Code CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which I use to start the vscode application. [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm) is the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) Package Manager which I use to spin up the Node.js dev servers.

Yes the code does work, it launches two instances of vscode, which I want. It also does work without ` | exit /b` but then the terminal window stays open which I don't want.

The only problem I have left is telling vscode to run "npm run dev" in it's integrated terminal, perhaps via the vscode CLI, or some other way.

Comment: Is`code` a batch file on its own? Is so, you need to use `call code`. `| exit /B` is nonsense, the pipe `|` is wrong at this place…

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this using [VSCode Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

First off, the code below is working, but might need improving. Please comment suggestions and I'll edit my answer.

1. Inside your projects root, if there isn't already a `.vscode` folder, then create it. Inside this folder, create a file with the name `tasks.json`. Inside this file, you will tell vscode to run the tasks you need. In my case, I will do "npm run dev" in the terminal/shell on startup of vscode.

`myProject/.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Start dev server",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "windows": {
        "command": "npm run dev"
      },
      "group": "none",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      },
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Create batch file to start vscode with specified directories:

```
@echo off
for %%p in (C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\Programming\nextjs-project C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\Programming\strapi-project) do code -n %%p | exit /b
```

Now when you launch your batch file, it will open up a new vscode instance for every specified directory, and if you have added a tasks.json inside your .vscode folders with `"runOn": "folderOpen"`, it will run those tasks.